# grunt wont install or doesn't properly

Tags: gruntjs, npm

I have tried `npm install -g grunt` and everything seems to work, but when I do `grunt serve` it complains that grunt isn't a command on `ubuntu 14.04`

I am confused as to what I have to do to get this work.

Answer (score 4):

First thing, you need to install `grunt-cli` globally, not `grunt`.

Second thing, are you sure `npm install -g grunt-cli` didn't give you any errors?

On Ubuntu, you will have to run it as root:

`sudo npm install -g grunt-cli`

Comment: I tried it as non root, got errors - then tried it as root - it worked. the issue is i still don't have grunt installed. I did the same for bower and it worked. `grunt {command}` tells me grunt isn't a recognized command.

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot. You need to install `grunt-cli` globally: `sudo apt-get install -g grunt-cli`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: `E: Command line option 'g' [from -g] is not known.` So I tried `sudo apt-get install grunt-cli` but got: `E: Unable to locate package grunt-cli` is this npm? or is it a ubuntu repo?

Comment: I should run away from this thread, so embarrassing. I'm doing a million things at once, please accept my apologies again. This is the correct command: `sudo npm install -g grunt-cli`